# Providing canvas2d image tint for Spritefonts

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl, tint, spritefont

I'm doing Spritefonts and currently implemented tint for it on WebGL!

[image: WebGL spritefont tint]

But on canvas2d i tried to do it via `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` but it shows following

[image: canvas2d spritefont tint problem]

As you see, Black pixels are also filled...

Here is my code...

```js
var size = 32;
var x = 200;
var y = 200;
var spacing = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    var q = fonts[0].info[txt[i]];
    ctx.save();
    if (q) ctx.drawImage(fonts[0].src, q.x, q.y, q.w, q.h, x + (spacing || 0) + (i * size), y, size, size);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

When trying with "darken" mode instead, It fills correctly but also it fills background (Which i don't want this...)

[image: canvas2d image tint when using "darken" mode]

I also tried with `ctx.getImageData()` and `ctx.putImageData()` but letters not shown

```js
var size = 32;
var x = 200;
var y = 200;
var spacing = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    var q = fonts[0].info[txt[i]];
    if (q) {
        ctx.drawImage(fonts[0].src, q.x, q.y, q.w, q.h, x + (spacing || 0) + (i * size), y, size, size);
        f = ctx.getImageData(x + (spacing || 0) + (i * size), y, size, size);
        for (var i = 0; i < f.data.length; i += 4) {
            f.data[i + 0] = 100;
            f.data[i + 1] = 100;
            f.data[i + 2] = 255;
            f.data[i + 3] = 255;
        }
        ctx.putImageData(f, x + (spacing || 0) + (i * size), y, 0, 0, size, size);
    }
}
```

The image i'm using is from [here](https://opengameart.org/content/8x8-font-chomps-wacky-worlds-beta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is better way i found:

1. Create canvas with dimensions that complies with spritefont image dimensions
2. Save context state in the created canvas
3. Set `fillStyle` of the created canvas context with spritefont text color (Tint)
4. Set `globalAlpha` of created canvas context to opacity
5. Fill created canvas background with spritefont text color (Tint)
6. Apply "destination-atop" composite mode in created canvas context
7. Reset `globalAlpha` of created canvas context to 1 (Default)
8. Draw spritefont image onto created canvas
9. Restore context state in created canvas
10. Then, Let default canvas context (Not created one) draw characters from spritefont image, So we let it draw part of canvas we created (Note that spritefont image fills all created canvas)
11. Done!

```js
var size = 32;
var x = 200;
var y = 200;
var spacing = 0;
var opacity = 0.8;
var color = "green";
for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    var q = fonts[0].info[txt[i]];
    var c = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
    c.canvas.width = fonts[0].src.width;
    c.canvas.height = fonts[0].src.height;
    c.save();
    c.fillStyle = color;
    c.globalAlpha = opacity || 0.8;
    c.fillRect(0, 0, c.canvas.width, c.canvas.height);
    c.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
    c.globalAlpha = 1;
    c.drawImage(fonts[0].src, 0, 0);
    c.restore();
    if (q) ctx.drawImage(c.canvas, q.x, q.y, q.w, q.h, x + (i * (size + spacing)), y, size, size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using "lighten" mode for black pixels with filling background, Then applied "darken" mode instead of "source-in" and all done!

```js
var size = 32;
var x = 200;
var y = 200;
var spacing = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    var q = fonts[0].info[txt[i]];
    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighten";
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.canvas.style.backgroundColor;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    if (q) ctx.drawImage(fonts[0].src, q.x, q.y, q.w, q.h, x + (spacing || 0) + (i * size), y, size, size);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "darken";
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.restore();
}
```